# Java: Can't read txt file in payroll project

Tags: java, eclipse

A payroll project example, once I upload it and build it on eclipse it shows this error. Why can't I read the txt file?

The `Employee.txt` file that I'm supposed to read

```
001
Employee A
Level 1
380

002
Employee B
Level 2
450

003
Employee C
Level 3
550
```

The error I'm getting, can not read the txt file.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Employee.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:196)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:139)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:94)
    at MainPackage.payroll.main(payroll.java:12)
```

The java code

```
package MainPackage;

import java.io.*;

public class payroll {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        boolean notExists = true;

        while (notExists == true) {
            // objects
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("Employee.txt");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            // Declarations
            String str = "", UserInput = "", tmp = "";
            String empcode = "", empname = "", emplevel = "";
            double emprate = 0;
            int ctr = 0;
            String timeIn = "", timeOut = "", holiday = "", overtin = "", overtout = "";
            double totalHours = 0, hours = 0, minutes = 0, tmpTime = 0, late = 0, undertime = 0, overHours = 0,
                    overMinutes = 0;
            double salary = 0, overSal = 0, tmpSal = 0, regular = 0;
            double tmpLate = 0, tmpHour = 0, tmpUndertime = 0;

            System.out.print("Enter Employee Code : ");
            UserInput = br.readLine();

            // loop through the text file
            while ((str = textReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(UserInput)) {
                    empcode = UserInput;
                    // found the userinput, store the details now
                    while ((tmp = textReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        // lets put everyline into a variable for reference use
                        switch (ctr) {
                        case 0:
                            empname = tmp;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            emplevel = tmp;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            emprate = Double.parseDouble(tmp);
                            break;
                        }
                        ctr++;

                    }

                }
                // System.out.println(str);
            }

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();

            // check if record exists
            if (!(empcode.equalsIgnoreCase(""))) {
                // display the record if it exists
                System.out.println("-------------------1 Details---------------------------");
                System.out.println("Name of the Employee : " + empname);
                System.out.println("Employee Code : " + empcode);
                System.out.println("Employee Level : " + emplevel);
                System.out.println("Employee Rate : " + emprate);

                // enter for time in and time out
                String CurrentDay = "";
                int ctr2 = 1;
                while (ctr2 <= 5) {
                    switch (ctr2) {
                    case 1:
                        CurrentDay = "Monday";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        CurrentDay = "Tuesday";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        CurrentDay = "Wednesday";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        CurrentDay = "Thursday";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        CurrentDay = "Friday";
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();

                    // ask for time in and time out for regular and overtime
                    // also ask if today is holiday
                    System.out.print("Enter Time In for " + CurrentDay + " : ");
                    timeIn = br.readLine();
                    System.out.print("Enter Time Out for " + CurrentDay + " : ");
                    timeOut = br.readLine();
                    System.out.print("Is today holiday? [y/n] : ");
                    holiday = br.readLine();
                    System.out.print("Enter Time In for Over Time : ");
                    overtin = br.readLine();
                    System.out.print("Enter Time Out for Over Time : ");
                    overtout = br.readLine();

                    // split the hour and minute
                    String tin[] = timeIn.split(":");
                    String tout[] = timeOut.split(":");

                    // time calculation
                    hours += (Double.parseDouble(tout[0]) - Double.parseDouble(tin[0])) >= 9 ? 8
                            : Double.parseDouble(tout[0]) - Double.parseDouble(tin[0]);
                    tmpTime = Double.parseDouble(tout[0]) - Double.parseDouble(tin[0]);
                    tmpHour = (Double.parseDouble(tout[0]) - Double.parseDouble(tin[0])) >= 9 ? 8
                            : Double.parseDouble(tout[0]) - Double.parseDouble(tin[0]);

                    // minute late and under time calculation
                    if (tmpTime <= 9) {
                        late += Double.parseDouble(tin[1]);
                        tmpLate = Double.parseDouble(tin[1]);
                    }

                    if (Double.parseDouble(tout[0]) < 17) {
                        undertime += 60 - Double.parseDouble(tout[1]);
                        tmpUndertime = 60 - Double.parseDouble(tout[1]);
                    }

                    // salary rate calculation
                    if (holiday.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                        tmpSal = (emprate / 8) * 1.1;
                        tmpTime = (((tmpHour * 60) - (tmpLate + tmpUndertime)) / 60);
                        hours -= tmpTime;
                        overHours += (((tmpHour * 60) - (tmpLate + tmpUndertime)) / 60);
                        overSal += tmpSal * tmpTime;
                    } else {
                        tmpSal = emprate / 8;
                        tmpTime = (((tmpHour * 60) - (tmpLate + tmpUndertime)) / 60);
                        salary += tmpSal * tmpTime;
                        // System.out.println(salary + " = " + tmpSal * tmpHour + " " + tmpLate + " " +
                        // tmpUndertime + " ");
                    }

                    // if there is overtime
                    if (!(overtin.equalsIgnoreCase("00:00") || overtin.equalsIgnoreCase(""))) {
                        String ovin[] = overtin.split(":");
                        String ovout[] = overtout.split(":");

                        double tmp1 = 0;
                        double tmp2 = 0;
                        double minTmp = 0;

                        tmp1 = Double.parseDouble(ovin[0]) <= 17 ? 17 : Double.parseDouble(ovin[0]);
                        tmp2 = Double.parseDouble(ovout[0]) <= 20 ? 20 : 20;
                        minTmp = Double.parseDouble(ovin[1]) + Double.parseDouble(ovout[1]);

                        if ((tmp2 - tmp1) <= 3 && tmp2 - tmp1 > 0) {
                            overMinutes = ((tmp2 - tmp1) * 60) - minTmp;
                            overHours += overMinutes / 60;
                            double overTmp = overMinutes / 60;
                            double overRate = (emprate / 8) * 1.1;
                            overSal += overRate * overTmp;
                        }
                    }

                    ctr2++;
                }

                System.out.print("Enter Date Covered : ");
                String covered = br.readLine();
                minutes += (hours * 60) - (late + undertime);
                totalHours = minutes / 60;

                System.out.println();

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Name of the Employee : " + empname);
                System.out.println("Employee Code : " + empcode);
                System.out.println("Employee Level : " + emplevel);
                System.out.println("Employee Rate : " + emprate);
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Date Covered : " + covered);
                System.out.println("Total Hours : " + totalHours);
                System.out.println("Overtime : " + overHours);
                System.out.println("Regular Income : " + salary);
                System.out.println("Overtime Income : " + overSal);
                System.out.println("Gross Income : " + (salary + overSal));
                System.out.println("Deductions");

                // tax and gsis deduction computation
                double tax = ((salary + overSal) * .10);
                double gsis = 0;

                if (emplevel.equalsIgnoreCase("Level 1")) {
                    gsis = (salary + overSal) * .01;
                } else if (emplevel.equalsIgnoreCase("Level 2")) {
                    gsis = (salary + overSal) * .015;
                } else {
                    gsis = (salary + overSal) * 0.02;
                }

                System.out.println(" * Tax : " + tax);
                System.out.println(" * GSIS : " + gsis);
                System.out.println("Net Income : " + (((salary + overSal) - (tax + gsis)) + 500));

                System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");

                notExists = false;

            } else {
                System.out.println("-------------------Record Doesn't Exists---------------------------");
                notExists = true;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to find what directory Eclipse is trying to open the file from. You can set the current working directory in the Run Configuration to help Eclipse know where to look for it.

Comment: The error says `FileNotFoundException` Make sure your file is in the same folder as that of the program.

Comment: Try to run execute `System.out.println(new File("Employee.txt").getAbsolutePath())` to see from which location you are trying to read. Does that location describe your file location properly? No? Where is it located? How does your project structure look like?

Comment: I presume you are on Windows, right click on your file see Location copy and paste that (that's absolute path to your file) and replace "Employee.txt" with that absolute path in your code.

Comment: BTW avoid `while (notExists == true){...}`. It is too easy to make mistake and write `while (notExists = true){...}` which will cause infinite loop. Instead use `while (notExists){...}` and for negation `while (!notExists){...}`.

Comment: @Pshemo thank you! Tried that line and it told me where to put that file.

Comment: It just told you where JVM looked for that file. It doesn't mean you *should* put it there. Generally it is better to have resources in folder designed to hold them to avoid chaos at top level of our project.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you move Employee.txt to your resource folder (src/main/resources) and then use

```
try (InputStream input = payroll.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Employee.txt")){
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(input);
    }
```

If you cant move the file, or you really need it to be wherever it is you can use:

```
File myFile = new File("c:\\full\\path\\Employee.txt")
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("myFile");
```